# Async/Await for data fetch in componentDidMount not giving result as expected

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get information from api in componentDidMount then try to check with console.log but console.log not giving expected result.

```
async componentDidMount()
  {
    SplashScreen.hide();

    await requestStoragePermission();
    
    await this.getSongs();

    for await (let track of allSongs.getTrackList()) { //<- this loop should done first
      this.getSongInfo(track); 
    }

    console.log("____________after api:")
    for (let track of allSongs.getTrackList()) { //<- this loop should done last
      console.log(track.name);
    }
  }


async getSongInfo(track)
  {
    await fetch('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track='+track.name+'&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json&limit=1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      if(result.results.trackmatches.track.length > 0)
      {
        track.name = result.results.trackmatches.track[0]['name'];
        console.log("set name done for: "+track.name);
        track.artist = result.results.trackmatches.track[0]['artist'];
      }
    })
}
```

giving result:

```
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.508]  LOG      Tracks Received:
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      /storage/emulated/0/Download/the-weeknd-starboy-audio.mp3
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      /storage/emulated/0/Music/TOTEVANB - New Born (Original Mix).m4a
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      ____________after api:
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      the weeknd starboy 
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:08.320]  LOG      set name done for: Starboy
```

expected result:

```
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.508]  LOG      Tracks Received:
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      /storage/emulated/0/Download/the-weeknd-starboy-audio.mp3
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      /storage/emulated/0/Music/TOTEVANB - New Born (Original Mix).m4a
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      ____________after api:
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:08.320]  LOG      set name done for: Starboy
[Sat Jul 04 2020 21:46:07.509]  LOG      Starboy
```

"console.log(track.name) loop" calling before "this.getSongInfo(track) loop", "console loop" have to wait for "getSongInfo loop" but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with

```
for await(let track of await allSongs.tracksList) {
      await this.getSongInfo(track);
    }
```

it was giving syntax error when

```
for (let track of allSongs.tracksList) {
      await this.getSongInfo(track);
    }
```

interesting

Answer (score 0):

it looks like :

```
for await (let track of allSongs.getTrackList()) {
  this.getSongInfo(track); 
}
```

Should be written :

```
for (let track of allSongs.getTrackList()) {
  await this.getSongInfo(track); 
}
```

I believe for async() is used when the iterables are asynchronous, I never used it myself so I can't tell you for sure.

Hope it helps

**Edit: sumup of the solution**

Fixed with:

```
for await(let track of await allSongs.getTrackList()) {
  await this.getSongInfo(track); 
}
```

The first await applies for the itterables, the second applies to the method that gets the itterables and the third applies for each iteration.

Something cleaner could look like :

```
const trackList = await getTrackList();
enter code here
for (let track of trackList) {
   await this.getSongInfo(track); 
}
```

of course you could keep the first await IF each iterable is a Promise

Comment: mm, allSongs.getTrackList() is asynchronous and it returns an array right ? if it is asynchronous then you're first await should also stay , you would have await after the for and then also before your this.getSongInfo(track);

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to put await before this.getSongInfo(track);

Comment: Syntax error fixed with

for await(let track of await allSongs.tracksList) {
      await this.getSongInfo(track);
    }

now it is works :) thank you

Comment: Great ! also I would recommend you to store your iterable before, like :

const trackList = await allSongs.getTrackList();

So you can get rid of the first await, then you should consider using either axios for requests or making your own abstract component, so you don't have to write all this code again and again for each fetch